# localhost on mavericks accepts one file, denies an adjusted version of same

Tags: d3.js, localhost, osx-mavericks, permission-denied

Recently set up localhost web Apache2 web server on my mac running mavericks for testing. Everything went smoothly (site up and running, page rendering correctly) until I added a revised version of the html file to the site. The original file runs fine (some D3 data visualization code) but the revised file results in a "permission denied" error. I'd post the full code for both files, but prob too long and person helping with dev is convinced it's not an issue with the file, but one with my sys config. Guidance most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a permissions issue on the updated html file. Went to file info and adjusted permissions to match the original html file and it worked.